# Bus or Buses in Subject-Verb Agreement

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

I've written the following sentence but am unsure if the subject-verb agreement is correct. I'm uncertain if the second "bus" should be plural. It doesn't sound right but I think the rule is applied correctly.

"School buses are equipped with flashing lights and stop swing arms that indicate to motorists the buses have stopped to pick up or drop off students."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each stop is a single incident happening to one bus, so I would use *...that a bus has stopped...* The whole fleet of buses don't stop all together!

Comment: I'd be inclined to 'the bus' not 'a bus'. Each [set of] indicator[s] is attached to a single bus… 'the bus' for each instance.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - Yes, that would be equally good.

Answer (score 0):

"*School buses* are equipped with flashing lights and stop swing arms that indicate to motorists that those vehicles have stopped to pick up or drop off students." [avoids repeating the word bus]

*A school bus* is equipped with flashing lights and stop swing arms that indicate to motorists *it* has stopped to pick up or drop off students.

I think for a general idea, either the plural or singular can be used.

Comment: I'm with you, but I think 'the bus' is stronger. [Not worth a third answer as there's nothing 'wrong' with the existing two.]

Comment: @DoneWithThis. The bus would just be specific.